# NUnit tests for class that uses static class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

Example code:

```
public class TestMe
{
        public TestMe()
        {
        }

        public string GetCustomerName()
        {
             var customer = MyDbManager.GetCustomer();
             return customer.Name;
        }
}
```

- MyDbManager is related to the DB. Therefore (for the unit tests), I would like to "fake" the DB call.
- MyDbManager is a **static** class that contains more than 100 methods.
- It is impossible to mockup the static class to make the relevant method
  return fake results.
- It will require too much work converting this
  class to a non-static one.

How can I test GetCustomerName?

Comment: You can inject a dependency in `TestMe` where the true implementation call `MyDbManager.GetCustomer` and the fake do a fake thing.

Comment: why do you want to test it at all? Your function doesn't do anything useful despite calling that static function. So chances are you should test *that one* instead.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain this is an example of a much more complex program. I just isolated the issue.

Comment: @vernou How can I inject the dependency with a static class?

Answer (score 1):

Static dependencies are a real headbreaker in legacy-systems, as you already noticed. There are a couple of things you can do, depending on how much you can change the code being tested. The cleanest thing to do is of course creating an interface from the dependency and inject that to your function. Doing that on a complex system may introduce heavy refactorings and thus many errors.

However your function to be tested just uses the `Customer` from that DB, so you may inject that customer to the function instead of making your function ask the DB for the customer itself:

```
public string GetCustomerName(Customer customer)
{
     return customer.Name;
}
```

Now it's pretty easy to test that function, as all you need is providing any `Customer`-instance to it. However you have a breaking change as your function now expects a `Customer`. In order to avoid that, you could use your static call as a fallback, when no `Customer` was provided:

```
public string GetCustomerName(Customer customer = null)
{
    if(customer == null) customer = myDbManager.GetCustomer();
    return customer.Name;
}
```

Now you can test the function by passing a `Customer`, while existing code won't change and can use the legacy-DB-manager. Now you can change every client of your function one by one and don't need to change the entire system at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can encapsulate the static part in dependencies, like

```cs
public interface ICustomers
{
    Customer GetCustomer();
}

public class Customers : ICustomers
{
    public Customer GetCustomer() => MyDbManager.GetCustomer();
}

public class TestMe
{
    private ICustomers _customers;

    public TestMe(ICustomers customers)
    {
        _customer = customers;
    }

    public string GetCustomerName()
    {
         var customer = _customers.GetCustomer();
         return customer.Name;
    }
}
```

Then you can mock (or fake) the dependencies to test, like :

```cs
public class TestMeTests
{
    [Fact]
    void GetCustomerNameWhenCustomerIsFridman()
    {
        // Init
        var mock = new Mock<ICustomers>();
        mock.Setup(customers => customers.GetCustomer()).Return(new Customer { Name = "Fridman" });
        var testMe = new TestMe(new FakeCustomers(mock.Object));
        // Run
        var result = testMe.GetCustomerName();
        // Assert
        Asset.Equal(result, "Fridman")
    }
    
    [Fact]
    void GetCustomerNameWhenCustomerDontExist()
    {
        // Init
        var mock = new Mock<ICustomers>();
        mock.Setup(customers => customers.GetCustomer()).Return(null);
        var testMe = new TestMe(new FakeCustomers(mock.Object));
        // Run
        var result = testMe.GetCustomerName();
        // Assert
        Asset.IsNull(result)
    }
}
```

PS : It's a xunit example, because I don't know NUnit.